# Load module depending on a parameter

Tags: angular, angular-routing, eager-loading, angular-module

I am trying to use the same Angular project to manage 3 websites (I know..) 
In my app I want to be able to load a specific module (eager loading) from the AppModule based on some parameters (the domain url).
And then the selected module will have its own router and will lazy load the rest of my component.

I try using router outlet but I need to use a proxy to have a component in my outlet router, here is what I have now :

**app.routing-module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {ComponentModuleOneProxyComponent} from './component-module-one-proxy/component-module-one-proxy.component';
import { ModuleOneModule } from './module-one/module-one.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    outlet: 'module-one-outlet',
    component: ComponentModuleOneProxyComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => ModuleOneModule
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'module-two',
    loadChildren: 'app/module-two/module-two.module#ModuleTwoModule'
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

But I'm keep getting an error :

```
 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined
```